# Maven multi-module project dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, setup-project

I have one project lets say A. It already has 50 different modules. Now I have to create one more module inside it.

My new module pom.xml has a parent entry for A pom.xml which is the main one. Also in eclipse only A is having properties information for build path. Other modules didnt have this.

So my problem is I want to add one jar in my newely created module. So that dependency entry will be in this sub module pom or in main pom file. When I tried with sub module pom, it is not working and the main pom already have some issue related to downloading for all  other 50 modules. So I m stuch here.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_When I tried with sub module pom, it is not working_" - what do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to see and what do you see instead?

Comment: I would first ensure that the POM builds cleanly before you try adding a new submodule. If I understand correctly (sorry English is not my first language) you also have other problems at the master POM level.